# Tensorflow bazel quantization build error

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, quantization

I am trying to build tensorflow tools package with bazel 0.18.0

following steps are ok

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensoflow
bazel build --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
bazel build --config=cuda //tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image
```

until trying to run this command line

```
bazel build --config=cuda //tensorflow/contrib/quantization:quantize_graph
```

it show error, so should i give something else then quantize_graph? and what i can use or find?

root@24663fb1018d:/srv/wu/tensorflow-src/tensorflow# bazel build --config=cuda //tensorflow/contrib/quantization:quantize_graph
WARNING: Duplicate rc file: /srv/wu/tensorflow-src/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc is read multiple times, most recently imported from /srv/wu/tensorflow-src/tensorflow/.bazelrc
WARNING: Processed legacy workspace file /srv/wu/tensorflow-src/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc. This file will not be processedin the next release of Bazel. Please read https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6319 for further information, including how to upgrade.
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
WARNING: The following configs were expanded more than once: [cuda]. For repeatable flags, repeats are counted twice and may lead to unexpected behavior.
ERROR: Skipping '//tensorflow/contrib/quantization:quantize_graph': no such target '//tensorflow/contrib/quantization:quantize_graph': target 'quantize_graph' not declared in package 'tensorflow/contrib/quantization' defined by /srv/wu/tensorflow-src/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/quantization/BUILD
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: **no such target '//tensorflow/contrib/quantization:quantize_graph': target 'quantize_graph' not declared in package 'tensorflow/contrib/quantization'** defined by /srv/wu/tensorflow-src/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/quantization/BUILD
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.195s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (1 packages loaded)

and then i tried with tools path, no luck

```
bazel build --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/quantization:quantize_graph
```

WARNING: Duplicate rc file: /srv/wu/tensorflow-src/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc is read multiple times, most recently imported from /srv/wu/tensorflow-src/tensorflow/.bazelrcWARNING: Processed legacy workspace file /srv/wu/tensorflow-src/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc. This file will not be processed in the next release of Bazel. Please read https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6319 for further information, including how to upgrade.WARNING: The following configs were expanded more than once: [cuda]. For repeatable flags, repeats are counted twice and may lead to unexpected behavior.ERROR: Skipping '//tensorflow/tools/quantization:quantize_graph': no such package'tensorflow/tools/quantization': BUILD file not found on package pathWARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: no such package 'tensorflow/tools/quantization': BUILD file not found on package path
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.506s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)

also the toco is not working

```
bazel build --config=cuda tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco
```

WARNING: Duplicate rc file: /srv/wu/tensorflow-src/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc is read multiple times, most recently imported from /srv/wu/tensorflow-src/tensorflow/.bazelrc
WARNING: Processed legacy workspace file /srv/wu/tensorflow-src/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc. This file will not be processed in the next release of Bazel. Please read https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6319 for further information, including how to upgrade.WARNING: The following configs were expanded more than once: [cuda]. For repeatable flags, repeats are counted twice and may lead to unexpected behavior.ERROR: Skipping 'tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco': no such package 'tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco': BUILD file not found on package path
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.ERROR: no such package 'tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco': BUILD file not found on package pathINFO: Elapsed time: 0.500s
INFO: 0 processes.FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify where targets are, look into the `BUILD` file in the package directory.

The `quantize_graph` target has been [moved to the `//tensorflow/contrib/quantize` package](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6a7bd8b8b34d541eba788b670c2cc7f489a1ae66/tensorflow/contrib/quantize/BUILD#L228). This should work:

```
$ bazel build --config=cuda //tensorflow/contrib/quantize:quantize_graph
```

The `toco` target [has been moved](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1a90c933a806812228a7b290cf670996cf1f674d/tensorflow/lite/toco/BUILD#L399) from `//tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco` to `//tensorflow/lite/toco`. Like `quantize_graph`, this should work:

```
$ bazel build --config=cuda //tensorflow/lite/toco:toco
```

Comment: Are there any potential risk of  `WARNING: The following configs were expanded more than once: [cuda]. For repeatable flags, repeats are counted twice and may lead to unexpected behavior.`